# Android Studio 4.1 layout editor can't select two elements

Tags: android-studio

When I click one element
then hold the shift key
and try to select another element
the first one is DE-selected!

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should hold the CTRL-key instead of the SHIFT key.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the thing is I was trying to select the elements in the Blueprint window. It worked when I made the selection in the Compoment Tree window.

[where I've been misdirected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3VxX.png)